# Change internet explorer security settings(initaize and script activex control not maked ...)

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer

How can i change internet explorer security settings by code.

I want to do the steps below but by code:

```
Tools -> Internet Options -> Security tab -> Custom Level ->
```

and initialize and script activeX control not make (Enable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\0\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\1\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\2\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\3\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\4\1609

[Change Internet Explorer settings programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840490/change-internet-explorer-settings-programmatically)

[Change internet explorer security settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462297/change-internet-explorer-security-settings)

[change IE settings Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226207/change-ie-settings-programmatically)